# JSON.parse error when making request to API

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a weather forecast app which utilizes the OpenWeatherMap API. However, when I make a request to the API, it gives me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data App.js:27
```

Here's my App.js:

```js
import "./App.css";
import Search from "./components/search";
import CurrentWeather from "./components/current_weather";
import { WEATHER_API_KEY } from "./api.js";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState(null);
  const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null);

  const handleOnSearchChange = (searchData) => {
    const [lat, long] = searchData.value.split(" ");

    const fetchCurrentWeather = fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${WEATHER_API_KEY}`
    );

    const fetchForecast = fetch(
      `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${WEATHER_API_KEY}`
    );

    Promise.all([fetchCurrentWeather, fetchForecast])
      .then(async (response) => {
        const weatherResponse = await response[0].json();
        const forecastResponse = await response[1].json();

        setCurrentWeather({ city: searchData.label, ...weatherResponse });
        setForecast({ city: searchData.label, ...forecastResponse });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Search onSearchChange={handleOnSearchChange} />
      <CurrentWeather />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I don't understand where this line 1 column 1 is supposed to be. I don't see anything wrong on line 27 either. What am I missing?

Comment: don't see anything wrong, does the response from the api contains json data ? I note that for the `fetchForecast` you forgot `https://`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé well that's the link the API website provides. I just copied it...